# windows rsync from different local drive, other than c, to remote

Tags: hard-drive, rsync

```
rsync -avz D:/test me@my.server.com:/test
```

I am using cwrsync on a windows7 box rsyncing to a linux box.

Everything works fine when i am going from a relative path on drive C.. but i need to rsync from another hdd in my windows box, drive d.

When i run the above line rsync moans that "the source and destination cannot both be remote
".

How can i get rsync to look at a directory on drive d?

The same line from a folder in drive c works fine:

```
rsync -avz /test me@my.server.com:/test
```

On a mac the 2nd hdd is mounted through Volumes and the rsync can access the files through that, is there anything similar in windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using a cygwin version of rsync then you probably should be able to use the `/cygdrive/` folder.  A drive with the letter D would be seen in cygwin as `/cygdrive/d`.

Comment: Thnaks :) that was exactly what i was after